# Criteria for a map of schemes to be an isomorphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $ X, Y $ be separated finite type schemes over an algebraically closed field $ k $.  Assume that $ Y $ is reduced.  Let $ \phi : X \rightarrow Y $ be a morphism of schemes.  Suppose that $ \phi $ gives a bijection on $ k $-points and an injection on $ S$-points for all $k$-schemes $ S$.  Prove or disprove that $ \phi $ is an isomorphism (or add some extra hypotheses to ensure that $ \phi $ is an isomorphism).

When $ k = \mathbb{C} $, $ X $ is normal, an $ Y $ is normal and irreducible, then I have a proof which uses the following crazy fact:
If $ X $ and $ Y $ are irreducible varieties over $\mathbb{C} $ and $ Y $ is normal, then a morphism $ \phi $ inducing a bijection on $ \mathbb{C} $-points is an isomorphism. 
My original question follows from this fact via a small tweaking of the usual Yoneda argument.

If anyone can give me a proof or reference for this last fact, I would be grateful too.  I read it in the appendix of Kumar's book on Kac-Moody groups.

**Edit:**  In light of some counterexamples, let me assume that X is irreducible and Y is normal and irreducible.

Comment: Why can't $X$ be the disjoint union of the affine line and a point, and $Y$ be the projective line (and the map be the obvious thing) for a counterexample? 

Comment: <TeX-pedant>It is usually much better to write `\$X\$, \$Y\$' than '\$X, Y\$', because of the resulting spacing and, in some cases, the fact that the math comma may be different from the text comma.</TeX-pedant>

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12767 for a related question.

Comment: And also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16786

Answer (score 5):

Trivial counterexample when $X$ is not connected: let $F$ be closed an nonempty in $Y$, $U:=Y\setminus F$ (assumed nonempty), and $X$ the disjoint sum of $U$ and $F$.

A bit less trivial with $X$ and $Y$ irreducible: $Y$= an irreducible curve with a node $y$, $X'$:=its normalization, $X$= $X'$ with one of the two points over $y$ removed.

The property holds, indeed, if $X$ is irreducible and reduced and $Y$ normal, assuming only that $X(\mathbb{C})\to Y(\mathbb{C})$ is bijective. In fact, in this case $f$ must be quasifinite and birational, hence an isomorphism if $Y$ is normal.

Answer (score 3):

[This is a minor comment on Laurent Moret-Bailly's answer; I'm too new to leave comments]

That the map $f$ in Laurent Moret-Bailly's answer is birational follows from Proposition 7.16 in [J. Harris, *Algebraic Geometry, A First Course*, GTM 133, 1992]; that it is an isomorphism from Zariski's Main Theorem.